# Reduce vertical space before letter's object

Tags: spacing, letters

I have a letter I'm writing in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,origdate]{lettre}%
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mltex}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\institut{identite}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Sir someone\\
Address\\
University}
\date{le 01/05/2020}


\conc{Thesis on blablabla}
\opening{Dear Sir Someone,}

\lipsum[2-4]
\closing{Je vous prie de bien vouloir agréer, monsieur, l'expression de mes meilleures et respectueuses saluations.}

\vspace*{0.5cm}
\encl{CV, Lettre de motivation, Lettre de recommendation, Relevés de notes}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and

file `identite.ins`:

```
%-% Pour supprimer le trait de pliure
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NoRule}{\renewcommand*{\rule@length}{0}}
\makeatother

\NoRule
\name{Me}
\address{\centering
first name \textsc{last name} \\
Adress \\
Zip \textsc{City}}
\email{email@mail.com}
\telephone{06-00-00-00-00}
\nofax
\lieu{\textsc{City}}
\signature{Me \textsc{Me}}
```

I can't manage to remove to vertical space before the `\conc{Thesis on blablabla}` command.

You can see in the following screenshot that I'd like the vertical space between University and Objet to be way smaller but I couldn't manage to do it with `vspace` command and a negative length. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple with `xpatch`.

*Unrelated*: with the French language, use T1 font encoding, not OT1. Also, `francais` is deprecated, use the `french` option for `babel` (and it is better to load it with the document class, so that all packages depending on a language option be informed).

```
\documentclass[12pt,origdate, french]{lettre}%
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mltex}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\institut{identite}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\concline}{\vspace*{-8pc}}{}{}%% adjust the value to your needs

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Sir someone\\
Address\\
University}
\date{le 01/05/2020}


\conc{Thesis on blablabla}
\opening{Dear Sir Someone,}

\lipsum[2-4]
\closing{Je vous prie de bien vouloir agréer, monsieur, l'expression de mes meilleures et respectueuses saluations.}

\vspace*{0.5cm}
\encl{CV, Lettre de motivation, Lettre de recommendation, Relevés de notes}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)